# Why does getting Django's CSRF token from a cookie fail on mobile Chrome browser?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, cookies

A web application in Django with React components currently has been tested and works on desktop Google Chrome, Microsoft Edge, mobile Firefox and mobile Brave browsers. Unfortunately, it produces errors on Google Chrome on mobile. The React components do not seem to recognize that there is a user logged in.

The CSRF token is transferred from Django to the React components using a cookie (similarly to the process suggested at: https://django.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/csrf.html).

```
// Set what happens when the database is called by React

// Define how to get a cookie (such as a CSRF token)
export function getCookie(name) {
  var cookieValue = null;
  if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
      var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
      for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
          var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
          // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
          if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
              cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
              break;
          }
      }
  }
  return cookieValue;
}

// Define generically what happens when the database is called by React
export function backendLookup(method, endpoint, callback, data) {

  // Convert the data being sent to the database to JSON form
  let jsonData;
  if (data){
    jsonData = JSON.stringify(data)
  }

  // Prepare a new request to a database
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
  
  // Prepare the URL where the database is accessible (the API endpoint)
  const url = `https://artformist.com/api${endpoint}`

  // Identify that the data that will be receievd is in JSON format
  xhr.responseType = "json"

  // Prepare the CSRF security token
  const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

  // Access the database, using the endpoint and method (such as "POST" or "GET") in use
  xhr.open(method, url)

  // Set the request header, for security purposes
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")

  // If there is a CSRF token...
  if (csrftoken){

    // Set the request headers
    // xhr.setRequestHeader("HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH", "XMLHttpRequest")
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest")
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken)
  }
  
  // Set what happens immediately when a request is made
  xhr.onload = function() {

    // If the status returned is a 403 error...
    if (xhr.status === 403) {

      // Get the details of the response...
      const detail = xhr.response.detail

      // If the response is that the user wasn't logged in...
      if (detail === "Authentication credentials were not provided."){

        if (window.location.href.indexOf("login") === -1) {

          // Redirect the user to the login screen TURNED OFF FOR TESTING
          // window.location.href = "/login?showLoginRequired=true&status=403"
        }

        alert(xhr.status)
      }
    }

    // // If the response is that something has gone wrong with the server 
    if (xhr.status === 500) {
      
      // If the user isn't at a login screen already...
      if (window.location.href.indexOf("login") === -1) {

          // Redirect the user to the login screen. TURNED OFF FOR TESTING
          // window.location.href = "/login?showLoginRequired=true&status=500"

          alert(xhr.status)
        }
    }

    // Manage the request response and status
    callback(xhr.response, xhr.status)
  }

  // If there is an error when the call to the database is made
  xhr.onerror = function (e) {
    
    // Manage that there was a 400 error
    callback({"message": "The request was an error"}, 400)
  }

  // Send the JSON data
  xhr.send(jsonData)

}
```

On Chrome mobile, the site has been producing 403 or 500 error depending on what the component is attempting to do.

Here are some of the production settings. The SameSite settings have been changed and the Django version has been upgraded.

```
CORS_REPLACE_HTTPS_REFERER      = True
HOST_SCHEME                     = "https://"
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER         = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT             = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE           = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE              = True

# Set whether requests can be made from different sites
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None

SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS  = True
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS             = 1000000
SECURE_FRAME_DENY               = True
```

Comment: It appears to work on a mobile Chrome browser on the iPhone but has issues on the Pixel 3 which I have been testing it on. Strange.